# Bash can I use both AND and OR in the same line?

Tags: bash

When I compile my code I usually do something like the following:

```
make remake 2> error.txt || less error.txt
```

Then if `less` doesn't pop up I copy my code to an `exe` directory.

I would like the copy command to execute automatically if the compilation is successful. For example I could do:

```
make remake 2> error.txt && cp ./bin/out.out ../exe/out.out
```

however then I would loose the useful feature that less pops up with my errors if the compilation fails.

Is it possible to combine both together?

Obviously

```
make remake 2> errors.txt || less errors.txt && cp ./bin/out.out ../exe/out.out
```

will not work, because the `&&` will cause the cp command to run every time I quit `less` (assuming it returns 0) in the case where the compile command fails.

Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do in 1 command-line line?

Answer (score 4):

Here you are:

```
make remake 2> errors.txt && cp ./bin/out.out ../exe/out.out || less errors.txt
```

Comment: .... wait a second... why does this work?

Comment: `&&` means AND, so **any** of the first 2 program has returned with error, then `less` will start. For the optimalization, if the first condition is false, then it skip checking the 2nd and immediately runs `less`. (if `cp` fails then less also will run)

Comment: Hmm I would have thought that the `||` would apply to the command before it - `cp` - interesting